# C# Serial Port Communication stops working after exactly 30 minutes

Tags: c#, service, serial-port

I have this windows service that is working exactly as expected except that after exactly 30 minutes it completely stops working.  The app should (and does, but only for 30 minutes) read incoming phone numbers from the serial port and return data from a database.  After 30 minutes the service keeps running but it doesn't read or send data anymore.  I have an event just to let me know if an error was received on the com port, but it's never fired at all.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            string fullpath = "C:/debug/debug.txt";
            File.AppendAllText(fullpath, "Started: " + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now) + Environment.NewLine);
            File.AppendAllText(fullpath, "Machine Name:" + Environment.MachineName + Environment.NewLine);

            var worker = new Thread(mainevent);
            worker.IsBackground = false;
            worker.Start();

        }
private void mainevent()
        {

            SerialPort MyCOMPort = new SerialPort();
            string COM_PortName = "COM2";
            int BaudRate = 9600;
            MyCOMPort.PortName = COM_PortName;
            MyCOMPort.BaudRate = BaudRate;
            MyCOMPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            MyCOMPort.DataBits = 8;
            MyCOMPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            MyCOMPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            MyCOMPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
            MyCOMPort.ErrorReceived += new SerialErrorReceivedEventHandler(ErrorReceivedHandler);
            MyCOMPort.RtsEnable = true;
            MyCOMPort.DtrEnable = true;
            MyCOMPort.Open();

        }
private void ErrorReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialErrorReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string fullpath = "C:/DEBUG/debut.txt";
            File.AppendAllText(fullpath, "WE HAVE RECEIEVED AN ERROR");
        }
private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
                string fullpath = "C:/debug/debug.txt";

                var ak = String.Format("{0}", ACK);
                var nk = String.Format("{0}", NAK);
                var sx = String.Format("{0}", STX);
                var ex = String.Format("{0}", ETX);
                var crt = String.Format("{0}", CR);
                var lfd = String.Format("{0}", LF);


                string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
                string prxData = indata.Normalize();
                string rxData = prxData.Trim();

                File.AppendAllText(fullpath, "rx:" + indata + "-" + Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now) + Environment.NewLine);

                if (rxData.Equals("H"))
                {

                    sp.Write(Convert.ToString(ak));
                }

                if (char.IsDigit(indata[0]) && firstpart.Length < 1)
                {
                    firstpart = indata;
                }
                else if (char.IsDigit(indata[0]))
                {
                    firstpart = firstpart + indata;

                    string nena = getNena(firstpart);

                    byte[] nenaascii = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(nena);

                    File.AppendAllText(fullpath, "Phone Number:" + firstpart.Substring(0, 10) + Environment.NewLine);
                    File.AppendAllText(fullpath, "Record Number: 2" + firstpart.Substring(10, 2) + Environment.NewLine);
                    sp.Write(Convert.ToString(ak));
                    sp.Write(Convert.ToString(sx));

                    sp.Write(nenaascii, 0, nena.Length);
                    sp.Write(Convert.ToString(crt));
                    sp.Write(Convert.ToString(lfd));
                    sp.Write(ex);

                    firstpart = "";

                    sp.DiscardInBuffer();
                    sp.DiscardOutBuffer();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string fullpath = "C:/debug/debug.txt";
                File.AppendAllText(fullpath, "ERROR:" + ex.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You mention that you're using _SerialPort_ but don't mention anything about the device.  Nor do you mention whether or not the device is inactive during the 30 minutes. Have you checked the Windows power settings (particularly USB selective suspending)?

Comment: I apologize for that, it's connected to a Lantronix UDS1100.  I know/assume that the device works reliably because there is another application which we are trying to replace that communicated with the serial port for months at a time without needing to restart.

Comment: Consider using a decent logging framework. But that is unrelated to your issue, probably.

Comment: Most likely the device you are connected to is going into a power down mode and closing the connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it possible that your 'MyCOMPort', being a local variable, is finally getting cleared up at some time in the future by the garbage collector/finalizer?  Try making it a member of something, so it is rooted and not available for deletion.

Comment: this is my guess as well